# Passing an Object from Angular Post to .Net ASMX

Tags: json, angularjs, c#-4.0, asmx

I have been trying to pass an object as a Post parameter to .NET asmx web service. I can pass primitive types such as int, string as parameters but I would like to pass the whole object because my class contains a lot of properties and it is very time consuming to pass each property individually.

My c# web service code is:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public ContactBLL AddContact(ContactBLL Contact)
{
   //add contact and return the contact object
}
```

I have added following statement at the top of the web service class:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

I have a second function in the web service which I call when my page loads in order to get a json ContactBLL object.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public ContactBLL GetContact(int ContactID)
{
    //return contact
}
```

I use following functions in my factory to call asmx web methods:

```js
factory.GetContactInfo = function (ContactID) {    
    return $http.post(serviceBase + 'GetContact', { ContactID: ContactID }).then(function (results) {
        return results.data;
    });
};

factory.InsertContact = function (Contact) {
    return $http.post(serviceBase + 'AddContact', { ContactBLL: Contact }).then(function (results) {                
        return results.data;
    });
};
```

In my controller, the GetContact function is called when the page loads and it returns the correct data to initialise the Contact object. I then call AddContact function and pass the object to factory function. The control doesn't get to the web service and I see the 500 message in chrome with the following message:
Message: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'Contact'."

Here is the code for the controller:

```js
var ContactController = function ($scope, $location, $http, $window, ContactService) {
    var Contact;
    Initialise();
    function Initialise() {
        Contact = {};
        GetContact(-1);
    }

    function GetContact(ContactID) {
        ContactService.GetContactInfo(ContactID)
        .then(function (data) {
            //do something
        }, function (error) {
            $window.alert('Sorry, an error occurred: ' + error.data.message);
        });
    }

    $scope.AddContactRecord = function () {
        ContactService.InsertContact(Contact)
        .then(function (data) {
            //do something
        }, function (error) {
            $window.alert('Sorry, an error occurred: ' + error.data.message);
        });
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or an easy way for passing tens of properties via Post call. The GetContact call works fine, however, I get error on InsertContact call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for the error. I was passing the datatype (ContactBLL) instead of the name (Contact) of the paramter in the AddContact function of my factory. The correct code is below:

```js
factory.InsertContact = function (Contact) {
    return $http.post(serviceBase + 'AddContact', { Contact: Contact }).then(function (results) {                
        return results.data;
    });
};
```